# exec() error, i cant figure it out how to make it work

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a script in the background but it's not working, this is the script I'm running:

```
$ddd = "script.php?titulo=".$_REQUEST['titulo']."&descripcion=".$_REQUEST['descripcion']."&accion=".$encrypta->encode('comunicadoPadres')."";

exec("wget -qO- $ddd &> /dev/null &");
```

If I run the url directly on the browser the script works but from this `exec()` nothing happens

Comment: Is this script local? Why don't you just `include` or `require` it? If you have control over it, write a function which you then call

Comment: Im trayin tu run it con muy hosting i verify with the Support tema and exec() is enabled

Answer (score 0):

`wegt` command only access path location, you can't compile&run php script if you want use `wget` then use  `HTTP` path of script

```
$ddd = "http://domain.com/script.php?titulo=".$_REQUEST['titulo']."&descripcion=".$_REQUEST['descripcion']."&accion=".$encrypta->encode('comunicadoPadres')."";

exec("wget -qO- $ddd &> /dev/null &");
```

Comment: have you checked http path in browser window?

Comment: Y es if i run the http path directly con tje browser... The script works fine

Comment: what is url, can you provide

Comment: Http://conectamesolutions.com/1111.php   this url  send 2 variable you can posr anything variables will be send to 2222.php

Comment: you have form on this link, suppose you want to access this `http://conectamesolutions.com/3333.php?titulo=&descripcion=&accion=Q9K6eMefUsX-2NC3rnKfYbgulRv1X-TbotFaDwJg4Fk
` use this url

Comment: Y es girish with that url directly con the browser the script works Just fine... The script sends massive emails if i use regular post method the browser fresee i need to run it con backgroud that why km traying to run it with the exec from 2222.php

Comment: setup cron job on server and schedule time

Comment: The cronjob works bit the emails has to be sended when a user submit the form

Comment: I Just recibe an email from the script

Comment: ok, you should use `333.php` in `exce` command, suppose your mail script on `333.php` file.. when user submit form then background script will work

Comment: Yes when user submit the form to 2222.php this exec's to 3333.php to send the email.... But its not working

Comment: `333.php` with query string

Comment: Yes the las variable (accion) is the one that  active the mass  emails